# What do you call the inverse of an ease-in-out curve for tweening?

Tags: animation, terminology

I understand that an ease-in-out curve starts slow, gets fast in the middle, and then ends slow. But what if I want the opposite of that? Starts fast, slow in the middle, ends fast? The reason is that I want to simulate a super-high jump. I'd like to use it but can't find any info about it because I don't know what it's called, and searching for "inverse in-out-ease" is not working out for me.

I'm sure people use this all the time on their websites but I just can't find any info on how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At [GreenSock](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Eases) we call this a [*slow-mo*](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Eases/SlowMo) ease (for slow motion). Our shortname for it in GSAP 3 is `"slow"`.

> I just can't find any info on how to do it.

As stated, in GSAP this ease (and many others) are included. GSAP also provides a [custom ease](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Eases/CustomEase) functionality (including the ability to modify existing ease curves) so you can get the exact ease that you need.

Here's an [example text animation effect](https://codepen.io/snorkltv/pen/84f7a5227e6ba0a3ee6f22d31d3be4f2?editors=0010) using GSAP's slowmo ease. Carl (SnorklTV) has an antire mini-series on GSAP easing including a focus on slowmo if that interests you. [Check it out](https://courses.snorkl.tv/courses/gsap3-special-eases?ref=44f484)!